# PHP, MySQL - efficiently determining access permissions based on distant parent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, recursion

I'm struggling to come up with an efficient solution to determine user access to a specified folder, using PHP (specifically Laravel) and MySQL. I want to create a system that has Google Drive-esque functionality...

For example, Joe Bloggs creates many folders within folders, e.g. `Level 1 > Level 2 > Level 3 > Level 4 > Level 5`. Within any of these folders, can be any number of additional sub files and folders.

This would be the resulting database structure -

```
Table name: users

| id | name       |
| -- | ---------- |
| 1  | Joe Bloggs |
| 2  | John Snow  |


Table name: folders

| id | parent_id | author_id | name      |
| -- | --------- | --------- | --------- |
| 1  | NULL      | 1         | Level 1   |
| 2  | 1         | 1         | Level 2   |
| 3  | 2         | 1         | Level 3   |
| 4  | 3         | 1         | Level 4   |
| 5  | 4         | 1         | Level 5   |
| 6  | 2         | 1         | Level 3.1 |
| 7  | 2         | 1         | Level 3.2 |

Table name: folders_users

| id | folder_id | user_id | owner | read | write |
| 1  | 1         | 1       | 1     | 1    | 1     |
| 2  | 3         | 2       | 0     | 1    | 1     |
```

So based on record 1 in `folder_users`, Joe Bloggs should have owner, read & write permissions for all folders underneath `Level 1`. Joe Bloggs, then gives John Snow read & write access to `Level 3`, which in turn should give Joe Bloggs read & write access to `Level 3`, `Level 3.1`, `Level 3.2` and anything created under any of these in future.

Additionally, it should be possible for a user to star a folder. I'd imagine this can simply be achieved with a separate table and query this separately -

```
Table name: starred_folders

| id | folder_id | user_id |
| -- | --------- | ------- |
| 1  | 7         | 2       |
```

The current solution I have is for every folder in the chain a user has permission to access, a record is created in the `folders_users` table. I feel like this is just overcomplicating things and creating excessive numbers of records. This is especially true when it comes to sharing a folder as I have to recreate the entire tree for that one user. Or, imagine if a user revokes write access to one of the shared users, the entire tree (potentially hundreds of records) has to be updated for a single flag.

What would be the best way to generate these trees, and to quickly and efficiently determine the user's access level in any given folder? I suspect the only way to do this is recursion, but I'm concerned about its efficiency? Or, should I perhaps be using something entirely different from MySQL for this? I've had a brief look into graph databases but I can't see it being a way forward for us as we don't have the infrastructure to support it.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as a solution not the most efficient one.

You can add a column to your `folders` table (let's call it access) and then put ids of people that have access to that folder and it's children. I assume when you want to show information about a folder you must get its parents information from table as well so you won't need to add new queries for that.

And if you just have a access definition you can simple add records to this column like `user1,user2,...` and if not you can serialize an array like this

```
[
    "read" => [user1,user2,...],
    "write" => [user2]
]
```

Of course you can add a column for each access but if you have so many accesses this might be a solution too.